# BIRT fail to generate pdf

Tags: pdf, birt

I am trying to download a pdf generate with Birt.
In this moment, the archive is downloaded in my desktop (save local, don't by browser), but a error ocurred and don't finish well.

Furthermore, i want that donwload through the browser and dont save in the desktop.
The PDF in the future Will be formed with parameters that the user fills in the web.

I use:

- Java 8
- Birt 4.6.0
- OpenXava 5.6.1

Here my code:

```
package org.openxava.datos.actions;

import org.openxava.actions.TabBaseAction;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EXCELRenderOption;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineConfig;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineConstants;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.HTMLRenderOption;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IReportEngine;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IReportEngineFactory;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IReportRunnable;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IRunAndRenderTask;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.PDFRenderOption;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.*;

public class Imprimir extends TabBaseAction {

    @Override
    public void execute() throws EngineException {

            IRunAndRenderTask task=null;
            IReportEngine engine=null;
            EngineConfig config = null;

            try{
                //System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "c:/temp/test/testsampledb");    
                config = new EngineConfig( );           
                config.setLogConfig("c:/dwn", Level.INFO);
                config.getAppContext().put(EngineConstants.APPCONTEXT_CLASSLOADER_KEY, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
                config.getAppContext().put(EngineConstants.WEBAPP_CLASSPATH_KEY, "C:\\Birt\\birt-runtime-4_6_0\\eventjar.jar");         
                config.setBIRTHome("C:\\Birt\\birt-runtime-4_6_0\\ReportEngine");
                //URL url = Imprimir.class.getResource("fonts/arial.ttf");
                //config.setFontConfig(url);
                //config.setLogConfig(null, Level.FINEST);
                Platform.startup( config );

                IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform
                .createFactoryObject( IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY );
                engine = factory.createReportEngine( config );


            IReportRunnable design = null;
            //Open the report design

            design = engine.openReportDesign("Info.rptdesign"); 

            task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);       
            //task.setParameterValue("Top Count", (new Integer(5)));
            task.validateParameters();

            //HTMLRenderOption options = new HTMLRenderOption();        
            //options.setImageDirectory("./");
            //options.setOutputFileName("C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/topn.html");
            //options.setEmbeddable( false );
            //options.setOutputFormat("html");

            PDFRenderOption options = new PDFRenderOption();
            options.setOutputFileName("c:/report/topn.pdf");
            options.setSupportedImageFormats("PNG;GIF;JPG;BMP;SWF;SVG");
            options.setOutputFormat("pdf");

            //EXCELRenderOption options = new EXCELRenderOption();  
            //options.setOutputFormat("xls");
            //options.setOutputFileName("output/resample/customers.xls");
            //options.setWrappingText(true);

            task.setRenderOption(options);
            task.setLocale(new Locale("en", "US"));
            task.run();
            task.close();
            engine.destroy();
            }catch( Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }               
            finally
            {
                if ( !task.getErrors( ).isEmpty( ) )

                {

                    for ( Object e : task.getErrors( ) )

                    {

                        ( (Exception) e ).printStackTrace( );

                    }

                }           
                Platform.shutdown( );
                System.out.println("Finished");
            }

        }   
}
```

Here error trace:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2375)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:191)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
at org.openxava.datos.actions.Imprimir.execute(Imprimir.java)
at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.executeAction(ModuleManager.java:535)
at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.executeAction(ModuleManager.java:443)
at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.execute(ModuleManager.java:404)
at org.apache.jsp.xava.execute_jsp._jspService(execute_jsp.java:256)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523)
at org.openxava.web.servlets.Servlets.getURIAsStream(Servlets.java:72)
at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.getURIAsStream(Module.java:214)
at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.request(Module.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontHandler.getMappedFont(FontHandler.java:213)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontHandler.selectFont(FontHandler.java:172)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontSplitter.buildChunk(FontSplitter.java:98)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontSplitter.getNext(FontSplitter.java:189)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.text.ChunkGenerator.getNext(ChunkGenerator.java:104)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.TextCompositor.getNextTextArea(TextCompositor.java:189)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.TextCompositor.getNextArea(TextCompositor.java:127)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.TextAreaLayout.layoutChildren(TextAreaLayout.java:182)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.TextAreaLayout.layout(TextAreaLayout.java:173)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.InlineTextArea.layout(InlineTextArea.java:70)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.startContent(LayoutEngine.java:562)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterAdapter.startText(ContentEmitterAdapter.java:147)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterAdapter.startLabel(ContentEmitterAdapter.java:153)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterUtil.startContent(ContentEmitterUtil.java:65)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitContent(LayoutEngine.java:713)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitContent(LayoutEngine.java:721)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.startForeign(LayoutEngine.java:764)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterUtil.startContent(ContentEmitterUtil.java:77)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitContent(LayoutEngine.java:713)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitChildren(LayoutEngine.java:737)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.RegionLayoutEngine.layout(RegionLayoutEngine.java:31)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.PageArea.layoutFooter(PageArea.java:489)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.PageArea.initialize(PageArea.java:249)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.RootArea.createNewPage(RootArea.java:147)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.RootArea.initialize(RootArea.java:138)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.setContainer(LayoutEngine.java:366)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine._startContainer(LayoutEngine.java:454)
```

Thanks for the help.
I answer any question

Have a good day and thanks for yout time.

Comment: I am no pro, but you get a NullPointer in `FontHandler.getMappedFont` and you have `config.setFont` specifically commented out. So there might be a reason around that.

Comment: By default there is a file with the usual routes, that is for your own fonts
Furthermore, with this line, it has same error : (

Comment: The folder containing the fontsConfig.xml file is the following:
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.fonts_2.5.1.v20090821

Comment: still you don't get a font - check the code for FontHandler.getMappedFont [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.birt.runtime/org.eclipse.birt.runtime/4.4.0/org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/layout/pdf/font/FontHandler.java) - it explicitly states that NullPointer when no font could be mapped.

Comment: check [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=449165) out. I can't help you any further, sorry.

Comment: Okay, it's something, I'll try again.
Thanks.

I will coment all that i do until it is alright